# Naming $\frac{x}{1-x}$ as a function

Tags: probability, functions, reference-request, terminology

I believe the name for the function $f(x) = (1-x)$ is the **complement of 1**. Is there a name for the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{1-x}$?

Comment: Is $x$ supposed to be the probability of an event and $1 - x$ the probability that the complementary event occurs?

Comment: welcome to ME ! I am also curious why probability tag appears because $f(x)$ e.g. on $[0,1]$ does not look like a possible probability distribution.

Comment: Of possible interest is that this is essentially the (standard) closed form expression for the sum of an infinite geometric progression: For each $x$ such that $-1 < x < 1$ we have $x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + \cdots + x^n + \cdots \; = \; \frac{x}{1-x}$ (i.e. first-term DIVIDED BY one-minus-common-ratio).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $x$ is the **probability** (as you have tagged the question) of an event and is in $[0,1]$

then $\frac{x}{1-x}$ is called the **[odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds)** of the event and is in $[0,\infty]$.

You can go further and say $\log_e\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)$ is the **log-odds** or **[logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit)** and is in $[-\infty,\infty]$.